# Как в bootstrap решена задача адаптирования сетки в зависимости от доступной ширины родителя (а не от ширины виюпорта)?

Tags: css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Не собираюсь изучать Bootstrap, но одно мне из него интересно.

Допустим мы определили, сколько конкретный компонент должен занимать колонок на маленьких, больших и средних экранах, а из обновлённого технического задания оказалось, что этот компонент будет использоваться как в одноколочном, так и в двухколоночном макетах.

Как в bootstrap решена эта задача?
Знаю, что эта проблема действительно существует, и Grid layout стал важным, но не последним шагом в её решении.

Из статьи ["Знакомство с CSS Grid Layout"](https://css-live.ru/articles/znakomstvo-s-css-grid-layout.html):

> Раскладка, основанная на медиавыражениях, привязана к области
> просмотра, это не подходит для изолированных модулей – компоненты
> должны адаптироваться к тому пространству, которое им доступно.

Grid layout решает эту задачу неидеально: что, если например нам нужно переменное расстояние между колонками в зависимости от доступной ширины или разная минимальная длина колонки для одноколоночной или двухколоночной раскладки?

Comment: Я тоже заметил эти недостатки, но хочу спросить:

1.`переменное расстояние между колонками в зависимости от доступной ширины`

Почему Вам не подходят относительные единицы измерения, единицы гибкости в качестве значения для свойства grid-gap с min-max функциями?

2.`Раскладка, основанная на медиавыражениях, ... – компоненты должны адаптироваться к тому пространству, которое им доступно.`

Без контекста вообще не понятно, что имелось в виду в этом предложении. Как понять только с помощью CSS, сколько пространства доступно для компонента? Без уточнений трудно дать свой ответ.

Comment: @highpassion, благодарю Вас за ответ! "grid-gap с min-max функциями?" - если я правильно понял, что min-max функция может применяться для grid-gap, то я об этом узнал впервые. "Без контекста вообще не понятно, что имелось в виду в этом предложении." - имелось ввиду, что один и тот же компонент можно поместить в широкую колонку с основным содержимым, а можно - в узкий сайдбар. Причём разрабатывая компонент мы заранее не знаем, какая ширина будет у его родителя.

Comment: "Как понять только с помощью CSS, сколько пространства доступно для компонента?" - с современным CSS может и никак, и это плохо. Ведь современная заработка ориентирована на компоненты, а компоненты не имеют права ничего знать о своих родителях, в частности - об их минимальных и максимальных ширинах. Концептуально, эту проблему можно решить, введя медиазапросы, основанные не на ширине вьюпорта, а на ширине родителя, по пока об этом можно мечтать...

Comment: да, это было ускорило написание view, да и сразу учитывается портретная и альбомные ориентации.

Comment: В таких случаях придется внешнему элементу задавать класс, который показывает, какая это верстка - в 2 колонки или в 1. CSS компонента в зависимости от класса родителя меняет свои параметры.

Comment: @Dzorogh, Так я и делаю. Недостаток такого подхода в том, что мы должны знать классы внутренних элементов компонента (хотя я понимаю, что другого подхода может пока не быть).

Comment: @БоковГлеб css вашего компонента, разумеется, должен знать классы своих внутренних элементов. В данной ситуации, он дополнительно должен еще знать класс-модификатор родительского компонента или глобальной области.

Comment: @Dzorogh, хорошо, с этим ясно. А что в bootstrap? Я правильно понял, что данный фреймворк никаких особых решений приведённой мной проблемы не предлагает?

Comment: @БоковГлеб эту проблему даже css не решает. А bootstrap это просто набор классов в конечном итоге.

Comment: @Dzorogh, тогда с Вашего разрешения, оформлю Ваш комментарий в виде ответа. На Ваше авторство я сослался.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: никак.

Как в комментариях указал @Dzorogh,

> Эту проблему даже css не решает. А bootstrap - это просто набор классов в конечном итоге.